# Typescript + nodeJS: import of fs becomes string

Tags: node.js, requirejs, typescript

I'm new with Typescript and with NodeJS.

For some reason this:

**GetMenuDataCommand.ts**

```
"use strict";

import fs = module("fs")
```

becomes this:

**GetMenuDataCommand.js**

```
  var fs = "fs";
```

Typescript - i love you - but why?

Comment: What version of TypeScript are you using? How are you compiling the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you referencing the `node.d.ts` file correctly? If TypeScript doesn't have a reference to the definition file for your import, it'll generate a string for the import instead of the expected code.

For example, I had the following:

```
import passport = require('passport');
```

and that was generating:

```
var passport = "passport";
```

Turns out I'd forgotten to reference the definition file. Adding a reference at the top of the file solved the problem:

```
/// <reference path="../../definitions/passport.d.ts" />
```

Arguably you should spot it easily because the TypeScript compiler would throw an error, but 0.9.x is somewhat bug-ridden and it doesn't always catch everything.

Answer (score 4):

I'm using TypeScript 0.9 the following code:

```
/// <reference path="node.d.ts" />

import fs = require("fs");

fs.appendFile('name.txt', 'Some data');
```

Produces the following identical output:

```
var fs = require("fs");

fs.appendFile('name.txt', 'Some data');
```

(In CommonJS mode - in AMD mode it does the below...)

```
define(["require", "exports", "fs"], function(require, exports, __fs__) {
    var fs = __fs__;

    fs.appendFile('name.txt', 'Some data');
});
```

Comment: Is `import fs = module("fs");` still the desired way to do this or has this changed in subsequent versions? as I could have sworn I read it was now `import fs = require("fs");`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if its related but in ts 0.9.x use require instead of module keyword :

```
"use strict";

import fs = require("fs")
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing types.

From the command line.

```
npm install typings --save-dev
node node_modules/typings/dist/bin.js install dt~node --save --global
```

You must include the `global` flag or else your text editor won't pick up the `.dt.ts` file.